# Способ образования слова прибежище

Tags: морфемы

Объясните, пожалуйста, какой способ образования у слова прибежище. Я определил как суффиксальный, а в ответах написано приставочный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ответили верно, может, не туда в ответ посмотрели.

Прибежище- место, куда прибежал,( итог по действию прибежать) - прибеж  + -ищ- суффиксальный

Бежище - прибежище - не по - русски, это не может быть приставочный.

Comment: Людмиоа, а что тогда считать производящей основой?  
Нсли прибег/прибеж, то это тоже "не по-русски".  
П если прибежал/прибегнул (подозреваю, что скорее уж второе), то получается, что выкинули один суффикс - и заменили на другой. Какой-то не совсем суффиксальный способ получается....   
Я ничего не утверждаю. Спрашиваю.

Comment: Начало словообразования - определение.Что это такое? Нельзя сказать, что прибежище - это бежище со значением приближения.Составляем цепочку, чтобы выяснить порядок, что от чего образовалось: бежать-прибежать (пр. основа бежа-)- прибежище(пр.основа прибеж-)
бежать-прибежать-(бежа-)прибегать(прибег)-прибегнуть(прибег).
Производящая основа - не основа слова(она бывает производной и непроизводной), а основа для процесса образования нового слова, производящая - общая основа для пары слов. Бежищ+ при=прибежище не получается.прибеж/а/ть -прибеж/ищ/е - общее - прибеж = это производящая основа.

Comment: Спасибо. Но я не ошибся. Сборник Бисерова, Текучевой. 
А как же будет на экзамене?

Comment: >Бежищ+ при=прибежище не получается
Прекрасно получается - как минимум, с теми же натяжками, что и "прибеж".

Людмила, Вы так не ответили на суть моих сомнений.
Попробую еще раз. Вы сказали, что "бежище" - это не по-русски, и только поэтому исключили другую возможную цепочку: бег / бежать (избегать) - бежище - прибежище. 
Но при этом в Вашей цепочке еще менее русское слово "прибеж", которое вы объявлеете производящей основой. 

Хорошо, а "убежище"? и для сравнения - "урочище"? 

И еще. "Бежище" вполне себе в ряду "пожарище", "пепелище", "кострище", "городище"...

Comment: Вот это проблема. Всяко бывает и на ЕГЭ. Могут быть сбои программ, тогда ответы точно не совпадут с ключами. В прошлом году так и было, но на апелляцию люди боятся подавать, потому что обычно при апелляции перепроверяют якобы только сочинение, а за него могут и ещё снизить. Но это неверно, должны проверить всё, а для этого всё должно быть прозрачным, т.е.каждый должен видеть задание , свои ответы и ключи, но нам до этого далеко. В прошлом году многие ученики заметили несоответствия, но побоялись идти на апелляцию, а зря.

Comment: Не поняла, куда делись ещё два комментария.Повторяю.Это не системная ошибка, а , скорее всего, опечатка.В брошюрках их полно.Когда я работала в школе,мы собирали все ошибки в методичках, отправляли в министерство образования, нам даже благодарность за это прислали. А сейчас молодёжь ленится это делать. Вот и появились снова ошибки, издания коммерческие, их плохо вычитывают. Что говорить, ошибки были и в министерских контрольных , были и  некорректные задания.(с двумя возможными ответами)

Comment: Согласна с Людмилой. Способ - суффиксальный. В ответах - ошибка. С данным сборником не работала. Но были у меня 40 тестов по подготовке к ЕГЭ просто Текучевой, без Бисерова. Ошибок - очень много.

Comment: Для behemothus.  "Выкинули один суффикс - и заменили на другой. Какой-то не совсем суффиксальный способ получается...".

Нормальный суффиксальный способ. Для существительных , образованных от глаголов, очень характерен. Про убежище Вы сами ответили. С другими суффиксами: выпекать - выпечка, читать - чтение и т.д.